# Sorting a collection

Tags: sorting, collections, plsql, record

I would like to sort a collection type and populate a new collection according to the DESC order of date. How do I go about it?

```
TYPE xyz IS RECORD(   

Item      aa.Item%Type,   
t_date       date,
Code     aa.Code%Type,
Qty       aa.Units%Type,
Cost      aa.Total_Cost%TYPE );


TYPE uxyz IS TABLE OF xyz;
l_uxyz    uxyz;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just to illustrate a very small example, i have mentioned a below
>   snippet. Hope this will help you out.

```
-- SQL Table type creation
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_NTT
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;

-- Anonomous block to illustrate your question  
  SET serveroutput ON;
  DECLARE
  TYPE lv_num_tab
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
  lv_num1 lv_num_tab:=lv_num_tab();
  lv_num2 NUMBER_NTT;
BEGIN
  lv_num2:=NUMBER_NTT(1,3,4,7,2,6);
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv_num1
  FROM TABLE(lv_num2)
  ORDER BY 1 DESC;
  dbms_output.put_line('With desc order');
  FOR i IN lv_num1.FIRST..lv_num1.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_num1(i));
  END LOOP;
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num1 FROM TABLE(lv_num2);
  dbms_output.put_line('Without desc order');
  FOR i IN lv_num1.FIRST..lv_num1.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_num1(i));
  END LOOP;
END;

-------------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------------

anonymous block completed
With desc order
7
6
4
3
2
1
Without desc order
1
3
4
7
2
6

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Will this be useful for complex record types?